# Running Linux configure error in Fix8 C++ library?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, debian

I am trying to run Fix8 at Fix8.org. I am following the README instructions as explained at:

https://github.com/dakka/fix8

I am getting an error when running the ./configure command? It results in:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

Does anyone have experience in fixing this? I m running both latest versions of Debian and Ubuntu Linux.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have libtool?  You might need to install it.  You might need autoconf/automake as well.

Comment: Hi Joe, I installed everything you mentioned. I still get the same error message so thanks so far

Comment: I ran ./bootstrap first and then could run ./configure. I wish the author mentioned that

Comment: @heavyrockerdude, then you should write your own answer and accept that, or accept Jan Hudecs writeup below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files mentioned in the error are placed in the source directory by autoconf and should be distributed in the release tarball. If they are not it's a bug, so please report it to the author.

If you have autoconf installed, you can get the files by running `./bootstrap` (or whatever script it has; the usual name is `./autogen.sh`), but you are not supposed to need autoconf to run configure script.

Comment: True, but it would not be the first time it happened.

Comment: Thanks too all who helped understand this

Answer (score 2):

Yeah sorry about that - you need libtool. I have supplied configure - as this was missing. Check the FAQ. If you have any more problems please email on the support group.